# Find pair of index values that minimizes the Euclidian distance between two meshgrids and a column vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, distance

I want to find the two find the pair of values and their index number in a meshgrid that a closets to another pair of values. Suppose I have two vectors `a= np.array([0.01,0.5,0.9])` and `b = np.array([0,3,6,10])` and two meshgrids `X,Y = np.meshgrid(a,b)`. For illustration, they look as follows:

```
X= array([[ 0.1,  0.5,  0.9],
         [ 0.1,  0.5,  0.9],
         [ 0.1,  0.5,  0.9],
         [ 0.1,  0.5,  0.9]])

Y =array([[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 3,  3,  3],
         [ 6,  6,  6],
         [10, 10, 10]])
```

Now, I have another array called `c` of dimension (2 x N). For illustration suppose `c` contains the following entries:

```
c = array([[ 0.07268017,  0.08816632,  0.11084398,  0.13352165,  0.1490078 ],
           [ 0.00091219,  0.00091219,  0.00091219,  0.00091219,  0.00091219]])
```

Denote a column vector of `c` by `x`. For each vector `x` I want to find 
[image]

To complicate matters a bit, I am in fact not only looking for the index with the smallest distance (i,j) but also the second smallest distance (i',j').

All my approaches so far turned out to be extremely complicated and involved a lot of side routes. Does someone have an idea for how to tackle the problem efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `X, Y` always come from `meshgrid()`, your minimization is separable in `X` and `Y`.  Just find the closest elements of `X` to `c[0,]` and the closest elements of `Y` to `c[1,]` --- 
you don't need to calculate the 2-dimensional metric.

If either `a` or `b` have uniform steps, you can save yourself even more time if you scale the corresponding values of `c` onto the indexes.  In your example, `all(a == 0.1+0.4*arange(3))`, so you can find the `x` values by inverting: `x = (c[0,] - 0.1)/0.4`.  If you have an invertible (possibly non-linear) function that maps integers onto `b`, you can similarly find `y` values directly by applying the inverse function to `c[1,]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer but i like to [... lots of stuff mercifully deleted, that you can still see using the revision history ...]

**Complete Revision**

As a followup of my own comment, please look at the following

*Setup*

```
In [25]: from numpy import *
In [26]: from scipy.spatial import KDTree
In [27]: X= array([[ 0.1,  0.5,  0.9],                                                
         [ 0.1,  0.5,  0.9],                                                  
         [ 0.1,  0.5,  0.9],
         [ 0.1,  0.5,  0.9]])
In [28]: Y =array([[ 0,  0,  0],                                                      
         [ 3,  3,  3],                                                        
         [ 6,  6,  6],
         [10, 10, 10]])
In [29]: c = array([[ 0.07268017,  0.08816632,  0.11084398,  0.13352165,  0.1490078 ],
           [ 0.00091219,  0.00091219,  0.00091219,  0.00091219,  0.00091219]])
```

*Solution*

Two lines of code, please notice that you have to pass the transpose of your `c` array.

```
In [30]: tree = KDTree(zip(X.ravel(), Y.ravel()))
In [31]: tree.query(c.T,k=2)                                           
Out[31]: 
(array([[ 0.02733505,  0.4273208 ],
        [ 0.01186879,  0.41183469],
        [ 0.01088228,  0.38915709],
        [ 0.03353406,  0.36647949],
        [ 0.04901629,  0.35099339]]), array([[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]]))
```

*Comment*

To interpret the result, the [excellent scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query)  inform you that `tree.query()` gives you back two arrays, containing respectively for each point in `c`

1. a scalar or an array of length `k>=2` giving you the distances
   from the point to the closest point on grid, the second closest, etc,
2. a scalar or an array of length `k>=2` giving you the indices
   pointing to the grid point(s) closest (next close etc).

To access the grid point, `KDTree` maintains a copy of the grid data, e.g

```
In [32]: tree.data[[0,1]]
Out[32]: 
array([[ 0.1,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0. ]])
```

where `[0,1]` is the first element of the second output array.

Should you need the indices of the closest(s) point in the mesh matrices, it simply a matter of using [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod).

Comment: Look at the docs for `scipy.spatial.KDTree`, the example given in the discussion of the `.query` method follows _exactly_ the description of your problem.